# Why cast a pointer to a float into a pointer to a long, then dereference?

Tags: c++, c, casting

I was going through this example which has a function outputting a hex bit pattern to represent an arbitrary float.

```
void ExamineFloat(float fValue)
{
    printf("%08lx\n", *(unsigned long *)&fValue);
}
```

Why take the address of fValue, cast to unsigned long pointer, then dereference? Isn't all that work just equivalent to a direct cast to unsigned long?

```
printf("%08lx\n", (unsigned long)fValue);
```

I tried it and the answer isn't the same, so confused.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. It's something that people did before C was standardized in 1989, and a few haven't kept up with the times

Comment: This probably doesn’t even work on 64-bit (LP64) architectures…

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
(unsigned long)fValue
```

This converts the `float` value to an `unsigned long` value, according to the "usual arithmetic conversions".

```
*(unsigned long *)&fValue
```

The intention here is to take the address at which `fValue` is stored, pretend that there is not a `float` but an `unsigned long` at this address, and to then read that `unsigned long`. The purpose is to examine the bit pattern which is used to store the `float` in memory.

**As shown, this causes undefined behavior though.**

Reason: You may not access an object through a pointer to a type that is not "compatible" to the object's type. "Compatible" types are for example (`unsigned`) `char` and every other type, or structures that share the same initial members (speaking of C here). See §6.5/7 [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for the detailed (C11) list (*Note that my use of "compatible" is different - more broad - than in the referenced text.*)

Solution: Cast to `unsigned char *`, access the individual bytes of the object and assemble an `unsigned long` out of them:

```
unsigned long pattern = 0;
unsigned char * access = (unsigned char *)&fValue;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(float); ++i) {
  pattern |= *access;
  pattern <<= CHAR_BIT;
  ++access;
}
```

Note that (as @CodesInChaos pointed out) the above treats the floating point value as being stored with its most significant byte first ("big endian"). If your system uses a different byte order for floating point values you'd need to adjust to that (or rearrange the bytes of above `unsigned long`, whatever's more practical to you).

Comment: Would `reinterpret_cast<unsigned long&>(fValue)` be allowed/defined in C++ (assuming the type sizes fit, of course)?

Comment: The original code works as long as the endianness of float and integers is the same (ignoring the UB). Your code assumes big-endian. I'd use a `memcpy` into `uint32_t` (and an assertion for matching sizes).

Comment: @celtschk I'd be very surprised if actually using that reference wouldn't count as a strict aliasing violation. -- "An lvalue expression of type T1 can be converted to reference to another type T2. The result is an lvalue or xvalue referring to the same object as the original lvalue, but with a different type. No temporary is created, no copy is made, no constructors or conversion functions are called. The resulting reference can only be accessed safely if allowed by the type aliasing rules" [(src)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Answer (score 4):

Floating-point values have memory representations: for example the bytes can represent a floating-point value using [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

The first expression `*(unsigned long *)&fValue` will interpret these bytes as if it was the *representation* of an `unsigned long` value. In fact in C standard it results in an undefined behavior (according to the so-called "strict aliasing rule"). In practice, there are issues such as endianness that have to be taken into account.

The second expression `(unsigned long)fValue` is C standard compliant. It has a precise meaning:

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer**
>
> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

`*(unsigned long *)&fValue` is not equivalent to a direct cast to an `unsigned long`.

The conversion to `(unsigned long)fValue` converts the value of `fValue` into an `unsigned long`, using the normal rules for conversion of a `float` value to an `unsigned long` value.   The representation of that value in an `unsigned long` (for example, in terms of the bits) can be quite different from how that same value is represented in a `float`.

The conversion `*(unsigned long *)&fValue` formally has undefined behaviour.   It interprets the memory occupied by `fValue` as if it is an `unsigned long`.    Practically (i.e. this is what often happens, even though the behaviour is undefined) this will often yield a value quite different from `fValue`.

Answer (score 3):

Typecasting in C does both a type conversion and a value conversion.  The floating point → unsigned long conversion truncates the fractional portion of the floating point number and restricts the value to the possible range of an unsigned long.  Converting from one type of pointer to another has no required change in value, so using the pointer typecast is a way to keep the same *in-memory* representation while changing the type associated with that representation.

In this case, it's a way to be able to output the binary representation of the floating point value.

Comment: "Converting from one type of pointer to another has no required change in value" , there may or may not be a change in the value representation. On  modern PCs and so forth there typically isn't.  But this is not relevant to OP's issue anyway, I think you meant to say something like, converting pointer type doesn't change the contents of the memory that the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already noted, casting a pointer to a non-char type to a pointer to a different non-char type and then dereferencing is undefined behavior.

That `printf("%08lx\n", *(unsigned long *)&fValue)` invokes undefined behavior does not necessarily mean that running a program that attempts to perform such a travesty will result in hard drive erasure or make nasal demons erupt from ones nose (the two hallmarks of undefined behavior). On a computer in which `sizeof(unsigned long)==sizeof(float)` and on which both types have the same alignment requirements, that `printf` will almost certainly do what one expects it to do, which is to print the hex representation of the floating point value in question.

This shouldn't be surprising. The C standard openly invites implementations to extend the language. Many of these extensions are in areas that are, strictly speaking, undefined behavior. For example, the POSIX function [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799) returns a `void*`, but this function is typically used to find the address of a function rather than a global variable. This means the void pointer returned by `dlsym` needs to be cast to a function pointer and then dereferenced to call the function. This is obviously undefined behavior, but it nonetheless works on any POSIX compliant platform. This will not work on a Harvard architecture machine on which pointers to functions have different sizes than do pointers to data.

Similarly, casting a pointer to a `float` to a pointer to an unsigned integer and then dereferencing happens to work on almost any computer with almost any compiler in which the size and alignment requirements of that unsigned integer are the same as that of a `float`.

That said, using `unsigned long` might well get you into trouble. On my computer, an `unsigned long` is 64 bits long and has 64 bit alignment requirements. This is not compatible with a float. It would be better to use `uint32_t` -- on my computer, that is.

The union hack is one way around this mess:

```
typedef struct {
    float fval;
    uint32_t ival;
} float_uint32_t;
```

Assigning to a `float_uint32_t.fval` and accessing from a ``float_uint32_t.ival` used to be undefined behavior. That is no longer the case in C. No compiler that I know of blows nasal demons for the union hack. This was not UB in C++. It was illegal. Until C++11, a compliant C++ compiler had to complain to be compliant.

Any even better way around this mess is to use the `%a` format, which has been part of the C standard since 1999:

```
printf ("%a\n", fValue);
```

This is simple, easy, portable, and there is no chance of undefined behavior. This prints the hexadecimal/binary representation of the double precision floating point value in question. Since `printf` is an archaic function, all `float` arguments are converted to `double` prior to the call to `printf`. This conversion must be exact per the 1999 version of the C standard. One can pick up that exact value via a call to `scanf` or its sisters.

Comment: Thank you for adding this answer, it helps clarify things even further! cheers.

Comment: Re "That is no longer the case in C" for the union hack, I'm pretty certain you're wrong. C11 6.5/7 states  the circumstances in which stored values can be accessed by an lvalue and, since `float` and `uint32_t` are not compatible, it's not permitted. The rules about only accessing unions with the same field used in the last store, still stand. Unless you have a later version of the standard that changes this but, since C17 was only created due to ISO rules limiting addenda before a new standard is required, I doubt they made such a fundamental change.