# How to convert byte*payload to an int?

Tags: arduino, type-conversion, esp8266, data-conversion, arduino-esp8266

I am programming ESP8266thing dev board using arduino.
I have a value stored in byte*payload. I want to convert that value and store it into an int variable. I tried different methods but non of them is working fine. Can anyone suggest me a good method ? Thank You!!

Comment: You should consider adding the things you tried so others can understand better what is that you are asking, without more information my guess is that casting the dereferenced pointer would be an option, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312058/why-cast-to-a-pointer-then-dereference

Answer (score 1):

How you do this depends entirely upon how you represented the value when you transmitted it via MQTT.

If you transmitted it in binary - for instance, you published the integer as series of bytes - then you also need to know the byte order and the number of bytes. Most likely it's least-significant-byte first (so if the integer in hex were 0x1234 it would be transmitted as two bytes - 0x34 followed by 0x12) and 32 bits.

If you're transmitting binary between two identical computers running similar software then you'll probably be fine (as long as that never changes), but if the computers differ or the software differs, you're dealing with representations of your integer that will be dependent on the platform you're using. Even using different languages on the two ends might matter - Python might represent an integer one way and C another, even if they're running on identical processors.

So if you transmit in binary you should really choose a machine-independent representation.

If you did transmit in binary and made no attempt at a machine-independent representation, the code would be something like:

```
byte *payload;
int payload_length;
int result;

if(payload_length < sizeof(int)) {
    HANDLE THIS ERROR
} else {
    result = *(int *)payload;
}
```

That checks to make sure there are enough bytes to represent a binary integer, and then uses a cast to retrieve the integer from the payload.

If you transmitted in binary in a machine-independent format then you'd need to do whatever transformation is necessary for the receiving architecture.

I don't really recommend transmitting in binary unless you know what you're doing and have good reasons for it. Most applications today will be fine transmitting as text - which you could say is the machine-independent representation.

The most likely alternative to transmitting in binary is in text - which can be a machine independent format. If you're transmitting an integer as text, your code would look something like this:

```
byte *payload;
int payload_length;
char payload_string[payload_length + 1];
int result;

memcpy(payload_string, payload, payload_length);
payload_string[payload_length] = '\0';
result = atoi(payload_string);
```

This code uses a temporary buffer to copy the payload into. We need to treat the payload like a C string, and C strings have an extra byte on the end - '\0' - which indicates end-of-string. There's no space for this in the payload and an end-of-string indicator may or may not have been sent as part of the payload, so we'll guarantee there's one by copying the payload and then adding one.

After that it's simple to call `atoi()` to convert the string to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you found an answer yet, but I had the exact same issue and eventually came up with this:

```
   payload[length] = '\0'; // Add a NULL to the end of the char* to make it a string.
   int aNumber = atoi((char *)payload);
```

Pretty simple in the end!