# What is the difference between (int)a and *(int*)&a

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm interested in What is the difference between `(int)a` and `*(int*)&a`. They have different outputs.

Comment: Note this site uses markdown. If you delimit code with backticks ("`"), it will be formatted as code. Otherwise, certain characters (such as asterisks) are interpreted as formatting. Read the formatting help (accessible when posting and the help center) for more.

Comment: What's the *type* of `a`? Can you post [mcve]?

Comment: the type of 'a' is a float

Comment: In addition to complete code, sample input and output/results (if any) should be included, including both expected/desired results and actual (if the two are different). Clarifications should be edited into the question.

Comment: Casting a `float*` to `int*` and reading as if it's an `int` object isn't allowed - `*(int*)&a` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Dereferencing the address of a pointer-casted variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56074903/90527)", "[What does i = * ( long * ) &y; do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47946741/90527)", "[Why cast to a pointer then dereference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39312058/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between the two expressions.

In this expression

```
(int)a
```

the value of the object `a` is converted to an integer value of the type `int.`

In this expression

```
*(int*)&a
```

the sub-expression `(int*)&a` says the compiler that there is allocated memory for an object of the type `int` that is that in the memory there is indeed stored a valid object of the type int. However the initial memory extent allocated for the object can be larger than an extent that stores a valid object of the type `int` or there can be stored not an object of the type `int` and as a result dereferencing the pointer can result in undefined behavior.

That is using the first expression the compiler tries to convert a value to a value of the type `int` while in the second case the compiler tries to interpret an extent of memory as it stores a valid object of the type `int`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    double x = 1.5;
    
    printf( "%d\n", ( int )x );
    printf( "%d\n", *( int *)&x );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1
0
```

And another example when using an expression like this `*(int*)&a` can produce a valid code and result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    struct A
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    } a = { .x = 10, .y = 20 };
    
    printf( "%d\n", *( int *)&a );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10
```

Comment: But here the double type is casted with int* , the size of int and the size of double are different , but the sizes of float and integer are the same , aren't they?

Comment: @user15111237 But the representations are different. I wrote about this "or there can be stored not an object of the type int"

Comment: Also if `#define a 5` then it will not compile